# addEventListner is not being assigned inside for loop (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a to do list, for a long while now. I can input a task by typing it in the input and then pressing +. However, when I create the new button, I assign it a eventListener, yet the button does not work when it is pressed.

I thought that the problem was that the code for eventListener function was in a outside function and was being 'summoned' yet that was not the case because it still didn't work.

I am planning to make the close function along the lines of `this.parentElement.remove()` but I first need to be able to get a simple `console.log()` working for the button before anything else.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input")
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add")
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){addTask()})

const todoList = document.getElementById("todo-list")

let task = document.querySelectorAll('.task')
let closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.close')

let taskArray = []

function addTask () {
    taskArray.push(input.value)
    input.value = ""
    renderTasks()
}

function renderTasks() {
    let taskList = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < taskArray.length; i++){
        let newTask = document.createElement('li')
        newTask.classList.add('task')

        let newP = document.createElement('p')
        newP.textContent = taskArray[i]

        let newClose = document.createElement('button')
        newClose.classList.add('close')
        newClose.textContent = 'x'
        newClose.addEventListener('click', function(){close()})

        newTask.append(newP, newClose)

        taskList += newTask.outerHTML
    }
    todoList.innerHTML = taskList

    task = document.querySelectorAll('.task')
    closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.close')
}

function check() {
    console.log('check()')
}

function close() {
    console.log('close()')
}
```

```css
.task {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.task p {
    width: 70%;
}

.close {
    display: inline-block;

    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/to-do.css">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Todo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="control-wrp">
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="type here">
    <button id="add">+</button>
  </div>
  <div id="todo-wrp">
    <ul id="todo-list">

    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="/javascript/to-do-list.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're adding dynamic elements, you can assign a delegate listener - where you place a listener on a static object, and then test that listener for the click you're looking for, like...

```
todoList.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('close')) close(e.target)
})
```

Then for your delete (close) function, you can use `element.closest()` to reference the container and just `element.remove()` it. `closest()` is better than `parentElement` as it protects you against certain future html structure changes

Event delegation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation

Element.closest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input")
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add")
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addTask()
})



const todoList = document.getElementById("todo-list")

todoList.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('close')) close(e.target)
})

let task = document.querySelectorAll('.task')
let closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.close')

let taskArray = []

function addTask() {
  taskArray.push(input.value)
  input.value = ""
  renderTasks()
}

function renderTasks() {
  let taskList = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < taskArray.length; i++) {
    let newTask = document.createElement('li')
    newTask.classList.add('task')

    let newP = document.createElement('p')
    newP.textContent = taskArray[i]

    let newClose = document.createElement('button')
    newClose.classList.add('close')
    newClose.textContent = 'x'


    newTask.append(newP, newClose)

    taskList += newTask.outerHTML
  }
  todoList.innerHTML = taskList

  task = document.querySelectorAll('.task')
}

function check() {
  console.log('check()')
}

function close(btn) {
  btn.closest('.task').remove()
}
```

```css
.task {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.task p {
  width: 70%;
}

.close {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/to-do.css">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Todo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="control-wrp">
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="type here">
    <button id="add">+</button>
  </div>
  <div id="todo-wrp">
    <ul id="todo-list">

    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="/javascript/to-do-list.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked wonders. And thank you as well for the recommendation on the element.closest.